# onActivityResult() Errors

Tags: java, android

Can anyone clearly explain why onActivityResult is producing the following errorsAnnotations are not allowed here

“;” expected

Operator ‘==‘ cannot be applied to ‘int’, ‘null’

cannot resolve method ‘getExtras()’

cannot resolve symbol ‘ACTION_CALL’

cannot resolve symbol ‘ACTION_VIEW’

Also can you explain how to fix it. Thank you.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.attr.data;


public class ContactIntentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int PHONE = 0;
    private final int WEBSITE = 1;
    private ListView intentListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private List<ContactObject> contactsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_intent);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // inflate my view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_intent);

        intentListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // initialize the list and add item
        contactsList = new ArrayList<>();
        contactsList.add(new ContactObject("Android One", "111-111-1111", "www.naruto.com"));
        contactsList.add(new ContactObject("Android Two", "222-222-2222", "www.naruto.com"));
        contactsList.add(new ContactObject("Android Three", "333-333-3333", "www.naruto.com"));
        contactsList.add(new ContactObject("Android Four", "444-444-4444", "www.naruto.com"));

        List<String> listName = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < contactsList.size(); i++) {
            listName.add(contactsList.get(i).getName());
        }

        // initialize the ArrayAdapter object
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ContactIntentActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listName);

        // set the adapter of the ListView
        intentListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // setonclicklistener in adapterview cannot be applied here. changed to setonItemClickListener
        intentListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ContactIntentActivity.this, ContactPageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Object", contactsList.get(position));
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            }
        });


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (data == null) {
                return;
            }
            Bundle resultData = data.getExtras();
            String value = resultData.getString("value");
            switch (resultCode) {
                case PHONE:
                    //Implicit intent to make a call
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + value)));
                    break;
                case WEBSITE:
                    //Implicit intent to visit website
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://" + value)));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Close your `onCreate` funtion: Add a `}` before your last `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Thank you C.L. that solved the issue. Can't believe I missed that during debugging.

Comment: Any advice on how to avoid stupid mistakes like that in the future?

Comment: You should use an IDE that hightlights matching braces (Android Studio does). Moreover, if you get multiple errors of different types starting at a certain point in your compilation unit, the reason may be that your expressions are not in the scope they belong to. Check your parantheses, espacially in the part just before your first error.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.